# How to add shadow to UIImageView itself instead of its layer

Tags: ios, swift, layer, shadow

I'm adding a shadow to a UIImageView with this method:

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func applyShadow()
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        layer.shadowRadius = 8.0
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

I want the content mode to be `.scaleAspectFit`. However, when I set that, the frame of the `layer` is different than the frame of the `UIImageView`, but I want the shadow to be applied to the frame of the `UIImageView`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The code you posted does apply the shadow to the frame of the `UIImageView`. It sounds like you want to apply the shadow to the scaled image in the image view, not to the image view.

Comment: No, just the opposite. Initially the image is stretched and the shadow is where I want it, but when I use .scaleAspectFit, the image gets narrower and the shadow hugs the narrowed image instead of the original frame.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set the backgroundColor of my `UIImageView` to white. Without a color set there was no content to the left and right of the image, so the shadow collapsed in on the `.scaleAspectFit` image. With a color set, the shadow is applied to the actual frame.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add shadow to image its Self by creeping new image with shadow

```
extension UIImageView {

    func addShadowToImageNotLayer(blurSize: CGFloat = 8.0){

        let shadowColor = UIColor(white:0.0, alpha:0.8).cgColor

        guard let image = self.image else {return}

        let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                                width: Int(image.size.width + blurSize),
                                height: Int(image.size.height + blurSize),
                                bitsPerComponent: image.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent,
                                bytesPerRow: 0,
                                space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!

        context.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: blurSize/2,height: -blurSize/2),
                          blur: blurSize,
                          color: shadowColor)
        context.draw(image.cgImage!,
                     in: CGRect(x: 0, y: blurSize, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height),
                     byTiling:false)

        self.image = UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!)

    }
}
```

**Used:**

```
 UIImageView().addShadowToImageNotLayer(blurSize: 20)
```